# Bootstrap 3.0 Center controls vertically in Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How I can center controls vertically in modal?

The problem is defined here: http://jsfiddle.net/3BpVF/2/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="text1">This is the longest label in the world and I want center all content on the right side in center of div row....</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <input id="text1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
</div>
```

I want center labels and textboxes vertically for every row in modal body.

Here is a picture of what I want:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2ah8dpx.jpg

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, even when I open the fiddle.

Comment: Can you please make a simple draw to make us clear what you really want?

Comment: Here is the picture: [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/2ah8dpx.png)

Comment: That photo shows vertical centring, not horizontal.

Comment: Uh, I had wrong perception about center something horizontal and vertical. I learned something new :) and I corected question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want... something like this?

**http://www.bootply.com/teloZUOCvD**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label>This is the longest label in the world and I want center all content on the right side in center of div row....</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label>Normal Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: My apologies for unclear question, but this is not what I want.
I posted a picture of wanted controls position in my question. 
Thx for answer.

Comment: Aha! So you actually mean you want to Center vertically!